# В codeigniter вызываю функцию PostgreSQL - ошибка типа

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter

Всем привет,
В codeigniter 3.1.0 средством pg_query вызываю  функцию PostgreSQL 9.3

```
 updateProduct( 0, 'Title text...', 'A', 'abr001', 1, 74.29, 53.81, 0, ' short description text...', ' description text...', 1 )
```

И получаю ошибку :

```
Message: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: function updateproduct(integer, unknown, unknown, unknown, integer, numeric, numeric, integer, unknown, unknown, integer) does not exist LINE 1: select * from updateProduct( 0, 'Title text...', 'A', 'abr0... ^ HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

И непонятно почему куча unknown-ов...
Функция определена как:

```
drop function if exists updateProduct();
create or replace function updateProduct(  p_id integer, p_title varchar(100), p_status Type_ProductStatus, p_sku varchar(100), p_user_id smallint, p_regular_price Type_Money, p_sale_price Type_Money, p_in_stock boolean, p_short_description varchar(255), p_description TEXT, p_has_attributes boolean  ) returns int as
$function$
declare
  r product%rowtype;
  begin
    ...
  end
$function$
language 'plpgsql';
```

Также определены 2 типа кторые я указал в определении функции:

```
CREATE TYPE Type_ProductStatus AS ENUM ( 'A', 'I',  'D',  '-' );
CREATE DOMAIN Type_Money AS numeric(10, 2) CHECK (VALUE >= 0.);
```

Знаю что для приведения тапов используют

```
 cast(? As varchar)
```

А как правильно ?

Спасибо!

---

Спасибо за разьяснения - помогло! И еще 2 вопроса:

1. Можно ли написать drop function так, чтобы удалялись ВСЕ функции вне зависимости от параметров?
2. А можно ли как передать массив и если да то как? В лоб это передать строку с разделителями типа "23,76,65" и на сервере
   парсит и выполнять. Есть ли лучшее решение?

Answer (score 2):

> , p_has_attributes **boolean**  )
>   ' description text...', **1** )

И ещё один идентичный аргумент вижу, но не хочу считать его позицию.

1 - это не boolean, это int. Postgresql заставляет следить за типами данных и не позволяет отстрелить себе ногу таким простым методом. Boolean - это true и false, их и передавайте.

```
updateProduct(..., true);
```

---

Кстати, обратите внимание на имя функции в тексте ошибки. lowercase, имена сущностей всегда в нижнем регистре. Парсер привёл к нижнему регистру самостоятельно, но лучше придерживаться схемы именования в нижнем регистре и через нижнее подчёркивание для объектов в СУБД, `update_product`.

Ну и раз уж всё равно ответ пишу - очевидное непонимание вот тут:

```
drop function if exists updateProduct();
create or replace function updateProduct
```

`create or replace` нормально обновит тело функции, если та уже существует. Изменение, например, выходных параметров, обновить не сможет, и такой drop function здесь тоже не поможет.

```
create or replace function updateProduct() ...
create or replace function updateProduct(t_id int) ...
create or replace function updateProduct(t_id int, name text) ...
```

Только что мы создали *3 разные функции*, а не обновили одну и ту же. В `postgresql` может существовать много функций с одним названием, но разным набором аргументов. Поэтому `drop function` должен вызываться с указанием типов аргументов той функции, которую надо удалить.